# Image download via node request module is corrupt

Tags: node.js, image, request, filesystems

I'm trying to download an image via the npm [request module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request), and save with [`fs.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), however the file is corrupt when saved on disk, verified with the imagemagick [`identify`](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) command.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const request = require('request');

const brandLogoUrl  = 'https://example.net/logo.png';
const filename      = path.basename(brandLogoUrl);
const brandLogoPath = `./${filename}`;

request(brandLogoUrl, (error, rsp, body) =>  {
        fs.writeFile(brandLogoPath, body, 'binary', (err) => {
            console.log('brand logo saved');
        });
    });
});
```

When I check the saved file with `identify`, the result:

> identify: improper image header `logo.png' @
>   error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3940.

However, if I download the same URL via `wget` and check it with `identify`, the result is

> logo.png PNG 283x109 283x109+0+0 8-bit sRGB 19KB 0.000u 0:00.000

The JS seems pretty simple, but seems there is something I'm overlooking. Can you spot it?

**EDIT**

I tried the https module (based on [this post](https://medium.com/@onlineinerview/simple-function-in-node-js-to-save-image-from-url-to-local-disk-server-fd627ae7f6a6)), and it works

```
var fs = require('fs');
var https = require('https');
//Node.js Function to save image from External URL.
var url = 'https://example.net/logo.png';
var file = fs.createWriteStream('./logo.png');
https.get(url, function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is the encoding of the response. When you make a request using this library, it's encoded as a string (`utf-8`) by default. According to the [documentation of the **request** module](https://github.com/request/request), you have to pass `encoding: null` to properly fetch binary data.

So your code should look like this:

```
request({ url: brandLogoUrl, encoding: null }, (error, rsp, body) =>  {
  fs.writeFile(brandLogoPath, body, 'binary', (err) => {
    console.log('brand logo saved');
  });
});
```

This is also the reason why `https` module worked well — it just passes raw data without any encoding.